# MotionEvent android : how to get the exact number of touches removed from the screen?

Tags: android, touch-event, motionevent

To detect the number of touches removed from the screen, I use this condition in my touch listener :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    //The condition :
    if(motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP)
    {
        System.out.println("############################");

        System.out.println("actionMasked : " + motionEvent.getActionMasked()+", touches count : " + motionEvent.getPointerCount());
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Then, when I put two fingers on the screen and then remove 1 single finger from screen, the console displays this :

```
actionMasked : 6, touches count : 2
```

But why does motionEvent.getPointerCount () return 2 touches instead of 1 touch when I only removed one finger from the screen ?

So how to get the exact number of touches removed from the screen ?

Comment: Pointer will be removed from motion event **after** UP event is delivered for it so it's logical you're still getting 2 here. Question is do following events (like move) keep returning 2?

Comment: Thank. Obviously, following events like move don't keep returning 2. But I need to get the pointer removed from screen in order to get its x and y coordinates.

Comment: Use [`getActionIndex`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent#getActionIndex()) to see which pointer is being lift up. I think you can't "remove" multiple pointers during one touch event, you should get separate motion event for each that's being removed.

Comment: Thank you very much, you solve the problem !

Answer (score 0):

YOU GET 2 because that function getPointerCount() returns The number of pointers of data contained in this event. Always >= 1.Any motion event would contain information about all the active pointers at the time an action occurs. so, when you have 2 fingers,and you lift one which is the second placed pointe, you get ACTION_POINTER_UP with info about both the pointers. When last finger is lifted, you get ACTION_UP.

your function should be like this :

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    //The condition :
    if(motionEvent.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP){
        System.out.println("############################");

        System.out.println("actionMasked : " + motionEvent.getActionMasked()+", touches count : " + motionEvent.getPointerCount() -1 );
    } else if(motionEvent.getActionMasked() ==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
      System.out.println("actionMasked : " + 
      motionEvent.getActionMasked()+", touches count : " + 
      motionEvent.getPointerCount()); 
 }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Thank, but I need to get the pointer removed from screen in order to get its x and y coordinates.

Comment: what do you mean by pointer removed? do u want the coordinates of the pointers when finger is moved up?